# How to store strings with apostrophes in a local macro

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I want to create a local macro (`phrases`) that stores a number of phrases:

> "I'm sorry"
>   "I can help"
>   "so what"

Evidently, some of these phrases have apostrophes in them and I do not know how to store them.

I have tried the following:

```
local phrases " `I'm sorry' "
local phrases `" `"I'm sorry"' "'
local phrases ` "I'm sorry" '
local phrases `" "I'm sorry" "'
```

However, none of these seem to work; Stata will not accept the phrase as a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
local foo `" "I'm sorry" "'

display `"`foo'"'
 "I'm sorry" 

clear
set obs 1

generate foo = `"`foo'"'

list

     +---------------+
     |           foo |
     |---------------|
  1. |  "I'm sorry"  |
     +---------------+
```